# C++ spcify types in template methods

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to create a class of static template methods:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>
#include<type_traits>

namespace InterpolationTypes
{
struct None{};
struct Linear{};
struct Lagrange3rd{};
struct Thirant{};
}

class Interpolation
{
public:
   template <typename SampleType, typename InterpolationType>
   static typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<InterpolationType, InterpolationTypes::None>::value, SampleType>::type
   interpolation(SampleType samples[], int index, float frac)
   {
       return samples[index];
   }

   // template <typename SampleType, typename InterpolationType>
   // static typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<InterpolationType, InterpolationTypes::Linear>::value, SampleType>::type
   // interpolation(SampleType samples[], int index, float frac)
   // {
   //  return frac * samples[index] + (1 - frac) * samples[index + 1];
   // }

   // template <typename SampleType, typename InterpolationType>
   // static typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<InterpolationType, InterpolationTypes::Lagrange3rd>::value, SampleType>::type
   // interpolation(SampleType samples[], int index, float frac)
   // {
   //  return -1;
   // }

   // template <typename SampleType, typename InterpolationType>
   // static typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<InterpolationType, InterpolationTypes::Thirant>::value, SampleType>::type
   // interpolation(SampleType samples[], int index, float frac)
   // {
   //  return -1;
   // }
private:
   Interpolation() = delete; // This class can't be instantiated, it's juce a holder for static methods..
};

template float Interpolation::interpolation<float, InterpolationTypes::None>;

int main(void)
{
   float samples[] = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f };

   std::cout<< "Interpolation type None -> " << Interpolation::interpolation<float, InterpolationTypes::None>(samples, 0, 0.5f) << std::endl;
   // std::cout<< "Interpolation type Linear -> " << Interpolation::interpolation<float, InterpolationTypes::Linear>(samples, 0, 0.5f) << std::endl;
   // std::cout << MyClass::MyMethod(MyEnum::First) << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Like this one.
My purpose is to specify which types combinations are accepted for SampleType and InterpolationType. A while ago reading across the web I remember of a solution looking like this one

```
template float Interpolation::interpolation<float, InterpolationTypes::None>;
```

but the error given me by the compiler is the following one

```
g++ -std=c++14 enable_if.cpp
enable_if.cpp:47:31: error: explicit instantiation of 'interpolation' does not refer to a function template, variable template, member function, member class, or static data member
template float Interpolation::interpolation<float, InterpolationTypes::None>;
                              ^
enable_if.cpp:18:2: note: explicit instantiation refers here
        interpolation(SampleType samples[], int index, float frac)
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Any help or hint is really appreciated.
Have a nice one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, silly mistake, i had to write the specification as follow

```
template float Interpolation::interpolation<float, InterpolationTypes::None>(float [], int, float);
```